# How to pass a String (Non managed bean) to a managed bean

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-ioc

I have a spring batch job. There is a step that is calling the reader method.

**STEP**

```
@Bean public Step myStep(FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer, Processor
processor,  @Value("${com.tableName}") String myTableName) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<MyBean, String> chunk(this.chuckSize)
        .reader(reader(myTableName, this.myRowMapper))
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build(); 
}
```

**READER** *Working*

```
@Bean
public <T> JdbcCursorItemReader<T> reader(@Value("${com.tableName}") String tableName, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<T> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    String query = "select * from " + tableName;
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(query);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);

    return jdbcCursorItemReader;
}
```

I want my reader to take dynamic tableNames. So I changed the reader to as mentioned below.

```
@Bean
public <T> JdbcCursorItemReader<T> reader(String tableName, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<T> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    String query = "select * from " + tableName;
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(query);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);

    return jdbcCursorItemReader;
}
```

This cause the following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method reader in com.walgreens.oracleextractionbatch.OracleExtractionJobConfiguration required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

I tried so many workarounds after intense googling. But I think I am missing something basic. Please help. TIA

Comment: Did you try defining the reader bean with prototype scope? By default, it is singleton scope and since there is no info about tableName, you are getting error. You are looking to get reader beans for different table names i.e. one bean per tableName. Try reader annotate with @scope("prototype") or @scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) and see if it works.

Comment: @Akash, I think that should solve the issue. I will try and let you know...

Comment: Did it work in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the scope of the **Reader**, **Writer** and the **Step** bean to **prototype**. I left the scope of processor bean as is(Singleton) because the processor logic is the same for all the scenarios.

Thanks, Akash

Answer (score 0):

Making Reader dynamic in the context of Spring batch is making them lazy.

We Can make reader and writer lazy by using `@StepScope`. With StepScope now We can pass parameters. The most popular way of passing Parameters are using `JobParameters` or using `stepExecutionContext`.

In your case , if you know table name at the start of job then use `JobParameters`

Sample Code for accessing `JobParameters` in Step.

```
 @Bean
        @StepScope
        public <T> JdbcCursorItemReader<T> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['tableName']}") String tableName), RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
```

If You are getting table name from some processing(in some previous step) then u need to set the table name in `stepExecutionContext`

This is how you can access table name from `stepExecutionContext`

```
 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public <T> JdbcCursorItemReader<T> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['tableName']}") String tableName), RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<T> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        String query = "select * from " + tableName;
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(query);
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);

        return jdbcCursorItemReader;
    }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. But before we get the value from stepExecutionContext shouldn't we set it. I did not set anything in the Step execution Context.

Comment: @Andy updated answer with some more details , hope this helps

Comment: The issue I faced is not with passing the value for table name param, But to create multiple readers with different queries [that's why differ table names] so that I can perform read operation on those tables. I fixed this using prototype scope.