# How to initiate a Spring Batch job from a RestController, passing an arry of Strings to the job?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on an application where a REST API can receive an array of JSON objects (each points to a file) to be processed.

I've created a Spring Batch job that uses a JacksonJsonObjectReader to read each individual object from the array, a processor that does what I need, and a writer that then sticks the object into the database. My batch configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class AddComicsConfiguration {
  private static final String KEY_STARTED = "job.started";

  @Autowired public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired private ComicInsertObjectReader comicInsertObjectReader;
  @Autowired private ComicInsertProcessor comicInsertProcessor;
  @Autowired private ComicInsertWriter comicInsertWriter;

  @Value("${batch.chunk-size}")
  private int batchChunkSize = 10;

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("addComicsJob")
  public Job addComicsToLibraryJob() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory
        .get("addComicsToLibraryJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(createInsertStep())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step createInsertStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
        .get("createInsertStep")
        .<ComicFileDescriptor, Comic>chunk(this.batchChunkSize)
        .reader(comicInsertReader())
        .processor(comicInsertProcessor)
        .writer(comicInsertWriter)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<ComicFileDescriptor> comicInsertReader() {
    return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<ComicFileDescriptor>()
        .jsonObjectReader(comicInsertObjectReader)
        .name("comicInsertReader")
        .build();
  }
}
```

The object reader class is:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class ComicInsertObjectReader extends JacksonJsonObjectReader<ComicFileDescriptor> {
  public ComicInsertObjectReader() {
    super(ComicFileDescriptor.class);
  }
}
```

And, for completeness, the class that's being represented in JSON:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ComicFileDescriptor {
  @JsonProperty("filename")
  @Getter
  @NonNull
  private String filename;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    final ComicFileDescriptor that = (ComicFileDescriptor) o;
    return filename.equals(that.filename);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(filename);
  }
}
```

The issue I'm trying (and failing) to solve is, how do I launch the job when a set of ComicFileDescriptor objects are received by the REST API? I've googled to try and find an example and can't find an example of initiating a job and passing data to it.

It seems that the answer would be in my REST controller:

```
@RestController
@Log4j2
public class FileController {
  @Autowired JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("addComicsToLibraryJob")
  private Job addComicsToLibraryJob;

  @PostMapping(
      value = "/import",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
  @AuditableEndpoint
  public void importComicFiles(@RequestBody() ImportComicFilesRequest request) throws Exception {
    final List<String> filenames = request.getFilenames();
    final List<ComicFileDescriptor> descriptors =
        filenames.stream()
            .map(filename -> new ComicFileDescriptor(filename))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 
   this.jobLauncher.run(this.addComicsToLibraryJob, new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters());
  }
}
```

I think I need to somehow take the filenames received by the controller (the descriptors variable) and pass it to the job. But how?

Comment: Are you basically looking for how to pass parameters to a job? I ran into this a couple years ago. Never wrote the complete example I was needing, but these answers got me on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926342/how-do-i-add-parameters-to-a-spring-batch-item-reader

Comment: I’m looking for how to start them job and pass on the array of objects to the job to be processed.